# Why does animated D3 example work in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, d3.js

This may be a simple fix, but I haven't been able to spot the problem. [This](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799) animated D3 example works fine in Chrome but not Firefox (both latest version). However, the [static version](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887193) of this example works in both browsers. I've setup both examples on a local server to inspect the elements. The path elements of the pie wedge slices are getting drawn under firefox, but they just don't appear. Hence, it seems like a CSS issue but the CSS looks fine to me. Could this be an issue with the animations for the pie layout under D3?

Comment: You should post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animated example is missing width and height attributes for the `<svg>` element. Per the rules on replaced elements this means it defaults to 300 x 150 in size.

Chrome is working on correcting this so that both browsers will work the same soon.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from the SVG tag, then it will also work in firefox. The truth is firefox is actually implementing the SVG correctly. It works fine in chrome because of a bug in webkit based browsers that doesn't respects `overflow` CSS property.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96163

You would also need to update the dimensions of your SVG and its contents for better results.